# Creating the Mint Pie Picker View

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, reverse-engineering, pickerview

Would anyone be able to provide some direction on how the Mint (the financial app, https://www.mint.com/) Pie Picker View was created, using Swift 3? 
I would want to use it for a color picker for my app, so all the pie pieces would be the same size and the pie pieces which each represent a different color. The pie is rotated using swiping gestures.

See image link below,
[http://imgur.com/a/trs9C](https://imgur.com/a/trs9C)

Answer (score 0):

ypu can create Pie by using [chart](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) library. for adding the gesture simply implement the UIGestureRecognizer